# Multiple-Choice Quiz: Scores not adding up correctly

Tags: vb.net

With my quiz finished, I went back to test it and found that the scores wouldn't add up correctly. I've gone over the code several times and it seems fine but I can't figure why it doesn't add the scores up correctly. I've created a subroutine that checks the correct answer and marks it which is then called to when the button is clicked.

```
Dim NoQ = ArQOP.NoQ
   Dim n As Integer = 1
   Dim rand As New Random
   Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
   Dim CorrectAnswer As String
   Public Score As Integer = 0
   Dim SelectedAnswer As String
   Dim username = Entry.user
   Dim Percentage As Integer
   Dim Grade As String
   Dim sqlString As String

Private Sub AnsCheck()

       Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb"),
               cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT CorrectAns FROM MCQ WHERE QuestionNumber = '" & n & "'", cn)
           cn.Open()
           CorrectAnswer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
       End Using

       If RadioButton1.Checked Then
           SelectedAnswer = RadioButton1.Text
       End If

       If RadioButton2.Checked Then
           SelectedAnswer = RadioButton2.Text
       End If

       If RadioButton3.Checked Then
           SelectedAnswer = RadioButton3.Text
       End If

       If RadioButton4.Checked Then
           SelectedAnswer = RadioButton4.Text
       End If

       If CorrectAnswer = SelectedAnswer Then
           Score += 1
       Else
           Score = Score
       End If

   End Sub


Private Sub NxtQues_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NxtQues.Click
       n += 1
       If n <= NoQ Then
           Questions()
           Answers()
           AnsCheck()
       Else
           SkipQues.Hide()
           NxtQues.Hide()
           EndQuiz.Show()
           StatsCalc()
       End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged this code? Does `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` return a value or `null`? Why don't also you load the answer(s) when you load the question(s)? You can set the currently selected option in the RadioButton's `CheckedChanged` event. (unrelated) `Score = Score` is not really useful, you can remove it.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` does return a value. If I'm honest that was the only method of marking I could think of

Answer (score 0):

You might have a type mismatch in `SELECT CorrectAns FROM MCQ WHERE QuestionNumber = '" & n & "'"` You have declared n as an Integer but you are trying to concatenate it into a string. Use parameters and you will avoid these problems. If you check your database to get the `OleDbType` you will see immediately what type of variable to assign to `.Value`.

`cmd.ExecuteScalar` returns an object so, it needs to be changed to a string.

I have a little function to get the selected radio button. In this case you pass `Me` which is the form. Many times the container control might be a GroupBox and you would pass the GroupBox.

I am not really seeing a problem with your code incrementing the Score.

```
Private Sub AnsCheck()

    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb"),
           cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT CorrectAns FROM MCQ WHERE QuestionNumber = @n;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = n
        cn.Open()
        CorrectAnswer = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using

    SelectedAnswer = GetSelectedRadioButton(Me).Text

    If CorrectAnswer = SelectedAnswer Then
        Score += 1
    End If

End Sub

Private Function GetSelectedRadioButton(ctrl As ContainerControl) As RadioButton
    Dim rButton As RadioButton = ctrl.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    Return rButton
End Function
```

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: I've turned on Option Strict, however when I do so I can't use the variables globally, I've also tried the code that you have sent but that does not seem to work as well.

Comment: `username`  will need a datatype. When you say "globally" do you mean within the form? At the form level `Dim` means `Private` and should be available all over the form. Where did my code fail?

Comment: I mean throughout the entire program. As in, when I call a variable from another form into this form it gives an error. Also, it doesn't really fail its just the fact that the scores don't add up properly. I just don't understand where it is going wrong.

Comment: If a form level variable is called from another class (form) it must be public of friend.

Comment: What I've done is: `Public username As String` in one form and then `Dim username = Form2.username`  but that has stopped working when I turn on Option Strict

Comment: Put a break point in your code by sliding your cursor to the left to the grey line. Click on the grey line and a red dot will appear. When you run the code it will stop at that point. You can examine the values of variable as you step through the code. Use the debug part of the tool bar to step. You can examine the variables  by holding your cursor over them and see what is going wrong.